# typescript object typing using an enum

Tags: typescript

I'm having a problem properly typing an object key to an enum. This is essentially what I have:

```
enum ItemTypes {
  WOOD,
  STONE
}

interface Item {
  owned: number,
  max: number
}

const stockpile: {[key in ItemTypes]: Item} = {}
```

I'm getting an error where `stockpile` is expecting the `itemType` enums to already exist within `stockpile`

Doing this works:

```
const stockpile: { [key: string]: Item } = {}
```

However, I would prefer it to be better typed as well as being able to export the enum to be used elsewhere. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THere is a big difference between  `stockpile` and `stockpile2`

```js
const stockpile: {
    [key in ItemTypes]: Item
} = {}

const stockpile2: {
    [key: string]: Item
} = {}
```

`stockpile` is and object with up front defined required keys `0` and `1`. So, TS forbis you to use empty object when it expects two keys

`stockpile2` is just indexed object. It means that there are no required keys/properties, however each key should be a string.

**Summary**

If you want to make required keys, you should use `[key in ItemTypes]` otherwise use `[key: string]: Item`

Hence, if you want to allow only keys from `ItemTypes`, use :

```js
enum ItemTypes {
    WOOD,
    STONE
}

interface Item {
    owned: number,
    max: number
}

type Stockpile = Partial<Record<ItemTypes, Item>>

const stockpile: Stockpile = {} // ok

const stockpile2: Stockpile = {
    0: { owned: 1, max: 2 }
} // ok

const stockpile3: Stockpile = {
    0: { owned: 1, max: 2 },
    1: { owned: 1, max: 2 }
} // ok
```

Please keep in mind, that numerical enums are unsafe. Please see [my article](https://catchts.com/safe-enums)

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) you can find documentation about utility types: Partial, Record etc ...

Comment: Hmmm I see. Is there a way to implement what i'm looking for or do you recommend me just using the indexed obj?

Comment: Just read ur edit. Guess ill be going with just an indexed obj. Thanks!

Comment: @Syn it depends what you want. Do you want to make all keys optional? Then use `Partial`

Comment: @Syn made an update

Comment: Interesting. I never used `Partials` before. This seems really good! I'll need to do further testing but I appreciate the help!